# Fragment error when trying to use FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm trying to create a swipe tab view in my app. But the problem I'm having is that my fragments need to be FragmentActivity becuase they have listview inside them.

So I think this is where I'm getting my error:

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    case 3:
        //Other fragment activity
        return new OtherFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

This needs to be:

```
public FragmentActivity getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    case 3:
        //Other fragment activity
        return new OtherFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I keep getting errors on this line:

```
public FragmentActivity getItem(int index) {
```

Error:

```
The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
My class is extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment can also have a ListView in it.

FragmentActivity is some support Class, to support Fragments on older devices, i think its pre api 11.

To use a ListView in a Fragment, just create a ListView in the Fragment, or inflate an xml file with a ListView in it.

Comment: Well the fragment has a list view and radio buttons. So for the fragment classes if i extend ListFragment, the adapter class still gives me that error because of the FragmentPagerAdapter getItem()

Comment: thats because you are using a listfragment, not a normal fragment as i suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

FragmentPagerAdapter getItem() method needs to return a Fragment. FragmentActivity is not a Fragment, it's an Activity containing Fragments. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Use ListFragment for Fragments having a ListView
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: be sure to import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment instead of android.app.ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment don't need to be FragmentActivity to hold a ListView, actually the Activity should extend FragmentActivity, and your fragment should extend [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), which is:

> a fragment that displays a list of items by binding to a data source
>   such as an array or Cursor, and exposes event handlers when the user
>   selects an item.

I made a post about it that explains how fragments work, how to implement a ListView inside a fragment and how to integrate Fragments with ViewPager. [Here is the link](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/10/20/working-with-fragments-and-viewpager-on-android), hope it helps.